# Unable to deploy a war on Tomcat7.0

Tags: java, tomcat

Hi I was trying to deploy a war on tomcat7.0. I got the following error message. Any idea to trace the problem.

```
 Sep 09, 2021 10:56:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy INFO: Undeploying context [/sbmvnoapp_schas]
 Sep 09, 2021 10:56:27 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sbmvnoapp_schas]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
         at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
         at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
         at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:986)
         at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:968)
         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5729)
         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:272)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1040)
         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1547)
         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1474)
         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1695)
         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:333)
         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1373)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1545)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1555)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1523)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please note [Tomcat 7's EOL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-70-eol.html) almost half a year ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your code is looking for a **JNDI** resource (***comp***) which doesn't exists.

Add a similar configuration relevant to your code in **server.xml**

```
<GlobalNamingResources ...>
  ...
  <Resource name="comp" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     description="Employees Database for HR Applications"/>
  ...
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

You can get more information from the [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html)

Comment: `java:comp/env` is not a resource, it is the [`Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html) that contains all the resources.

Comment: Thanks for helpful comments. I rebuilt the war and uploaded it. It worked then.  But I have no idea what has gone wrong.